# Magento Multiple Wishlist creation programmatically

Tags: magento, merge, admin

I know how to add products to a customer's wishlist programmatically however it only adds to one wishlist. I have the multiple wishlist option set to enabled however I do not know how to create a new wishlist instead of merging products into the existing wishlist.

```
public function submitQuote(Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote $quote)
{
    $currentQuote = $quote->getQuote();

    $customer = $currentQuote->getCustomer();

    $items = $currentQuote->getAllVisibleItems();

    //$wishlist = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlist();
    //Mage::register('wishlist', $wishlist);
    $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
    $curretDate = date('m/d/Y', time());
    $wishlist->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
    $wishlist->setName('Quote ' . $curretDate)
    ->setVisibility(false)
    ->generateSharingCode()
    ->save();

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        $productId = $item->getProductId();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $buyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest();

        $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
        if(is_string($result))
        {
            Mage::throwException($result);
        }
        $wishlist->save();
    }       

    //Mage::unregister('wishlist');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before. To add a product to a customer's wishlist you need to start a wishlist model and call the addNewItem method passing the product object. Here is how I do it.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$customer_id = 1;
$product_id = 1;
$customer->load($customer_id);
$wishlist->loadByCustomer($customer_id);
$wishlist->addNewItem($product->load($product_id));
```

Hope this helps!

EDITED:

```
$customerid= "YOUR CUSTOMER ID "; // Modify This
$customer=Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($customerid);
$wishlist=Mage::getModel("wishlist/wishlist")->loadByCustomer($customer,true);
```

Check for reference this: app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php

LATEST EDIT:

I see that your problem is here:

```
$result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
```

FINAL EDIT:

Then create another function and add the items and wishlist you want to add it to (as parameters). This should add items to the wishlist that you have passed as an argument when calling the function. Its the only solution I can come up with. Hope this helps!

Comment: That is what I am currently doing however it is adding it to the same wishlist instead of creating a new one

Comment: Still added it to the first wishlist instead of creating a new one

Comment: @RobertZeno maybe then I can see what the problem is

Comment: @RobertZeno check the answer I posted, I think I found the bug

Comment: I should have explained a little bit better. I want them all to go into the same wishlist however I want to create a new wishlist to put them all in as of right now they are just going into an existing wishlist

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this question because I'm trying to do something similar - your code part helped me to create a new wishlist, and I've managed to do the rest so thought I'd share.

This code will;

Create a new wishlist with the name 'Quote dd/mm/YY h:m:s'

Load the wishlist collection for the current user, ordered by highest ID first

Load the newest wishlist

Add all basket items to it

Redirect the user to the new wishlist view.

```
public function addToQuoteAction() {

            if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            $customerId = $customerData->getId();
            } else {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Please login to use this feature'));
                return $this->_redirectUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
            }

            // Create the wishlist
            $newWishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
            $curretDate = date('d/m/Y h:m:s', time());
            $newWishlist->setCustomerId($customerId);
            $newWishlist->setName('Quote ' . $curretDate)
                ->setVisibility(false)
                ->generateSharingCode()
                ->save();

            // Find the newly create list and load it
            $wishlistCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)->setOrder('wishlist_id');;

            $firstWish = $wishlistCollection->getFirstItem();

            $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->load($firstWish->getWishlistId());
            $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

            //getAllItems
            foreach ($cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                                    $productId  = $item->getProductId();
                $buyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest();
                $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($productId, $buyRequest);
                $wishlist->save();
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('All items have been moved to your quote'));
            return $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl().'wishlist/index/index/wishlist_id/'.$firstWish->getWishlistId().'/');
    }
```